# How do I pass string to a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

So I am trying to do this:

```
http://localhost:43751/api/doWork/asdfasfsaf
```

And here is Controller:

```
public class DoWorkController : ApiController
{
    public User GetWork(String input) {
        Dictionary<int, Work> users = DataObjects.Work.find(input);
        return users.Values.First<Work>();
    }

}
```

I run it and it doesn't work:

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI `'http://localhost:43751/api/doWork/asdfasfsaf'`.

and

> No action was found on the controller 'DoWork' that matches the request.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my Routing Configuration:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you change `String input` to `String id`? Can you show us your Web API routing?

Comment: @Ric Actually, with Web API, you typically don't include the action name in the URL. By convention, any action that begins with "Get" will be matched to any "GET" request.

Comment: @ChrisHardie that sounds interesting. I'll retract my comment.

Comment: @ChrisHardie in that case would he not want `/api/Work/asdfasfsaf`?

Comment: In this case, the URL would be `http://localhost:43751/api/DoWork/Work?input=asdfasfsaf`. [The HTTP method serves as the prefix for the action name](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: @Kami, because the controller is called "DoWorkController", by convention, you would call /api/DoWork/somestring - the controller part of the name should be removed in the URl

Comment: @Stijn  No Short form URL?  That look so Ugly.

Comment: @YongkeBillYu Web API can either grab the argument from a querystring variable or a URL segment, depends on how you are mapping things

Comment: @YongkeBillYu if you want `http://localhost:43751/api/DoWork/Work/asdfasfsaf` you either need to change your action's parameter to `id` or you need to change your route to accept `input` as part of the route.

Comment: Ok, got it to work, indeed, the Function should had been called GetDoWork, instead of GetWork.

Comment: I will post final results.

Answer (score 0):

It seem that all I needed to do to get this to work is this:

```
public class DoWorkController : ApiController{
    public User GetDoWork(String ID) {
        Dictionary<int, Work> users = DataObjects.Work.find(input);
        return users.Values.First<Work>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because MVC believes you're referring to a different URL. You need to either define a method that is listening to your requests of type HttpGet or HttpPost:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult doWork(string input) {
 // do processing and return the selected user as a model back to the view
 User user = YourGetUserMethod(input);
 return View(user);
}
```

so you could invoke it as: /api/doWork?input=asdfasfsaf

Or if what you want is to change your URL routing to accept the last portion of your URL as a parameter, you'd need to add something like this to your RouteConfig.cs file:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
   url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "DoWork", action = "doWork", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

You might want to follow [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx) for additional information regarding route mapping